# Choosing a book to gain general knowledge about biology

Tags: book-recommendation

I will be first year undergraduate at Physics department next year and last year I was at the Medicine faculty. I want do double major in the second year of faculty with Molecular Biology and Genetics. The intersection of biology and physics is my interest. I have two books about biology, first one is **What is Life?-Mind and Matter by Erwin Schrödinger** and the second one is **This is Biology by Ernst Mayr**. Which one should I read to acquire general knowledge about Biology?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The books you have**

The books you cited won't help you to get a solid and general basic knowledge in biology. I haven't read those books but I think that `This is Biology` is a book of philosophy of biology written by a biologist and philosopher. `What is life` is a very influential book written by a physicist who more or less predicted the structure of DNA that was later discovered by Watson and Crick. You won't learn much of biology through these books.

**Book Suggestions**

[This post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10376/introductory-biology-text-for-an-outsider) offers book suggestions for general introductory biology. [Here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21475/books-for-beginners/21477#21477) is another post that may also interest you

If you are interested in a specific field of biology, then you may want to ask for book suggestions for this particular field. I think that most biologists that come from a background in physics are in the fields of theoretical evolutionary biology, bioinformatics and biophysics (incl. molecular biophysics).

Here are a bunch of other posts asking for book recommendations that I imagine you may like reading about.

- [What physics knowledge can be applied to biology of organisms and ecosystems?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27450/what-physics-knowledge-can-be-applied-to-biology-of-organisms-and-ecosystems)
- [Book recommendations for algorithms used in evolutionary biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14168/book-recommendations-for-algorithms-used-in-evolutionary-biology)
- [Book recommendations for evolutionary models](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16577/book-recommendations-for-evolutionary-models)
- [How to learn biomathematics?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9243/how-to-learn-biomathematics/9245#9245)
- [Book recommendation on population/evolutionary genetics?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16470/book-recommendation-on-population-evolutionary-genetics)
- [Introductory literature for synthetic / systems biology?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2580/introductory-literature-for-synthetic-systems-biology)

And eventually you may want to read [Value of mathematical models in biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/34846/value-of-mathematical-models-in-biology) although the post has been closed.

Of course, you might want to read a bunch of wikipedia pages such as [Biophysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biophysics), [Molecular Biophysics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_biophysics), [Mathematical and Theoretical Biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_and_theoretical_biology#Mathematical_biophysics), [Biostatistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biostatistics), [Computational Biology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_biology), [Bioinformatics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioinformatics).